# Automatic incremental bootable off-site online backup

Tags: dropbox, carbon-copy-cloner

I'm looking for a way to clone my hard disk and have that clone be stored online. If my house burns down I could then download the disk file and mount it, so I could pick up from where I left off.

Currently I have set up Carbon Copy Cloner to make a bootable incremental image (sparsebundle) and store it on disk mounted over wifi (the disk is connected to a Time Capsule).

How do I incrementally upload my sparsebundle located on network disk to Dropbox or any other off-site service?

**What I have tried**

The Dropbox app was a no-go, because it doesn't support network disks.

CrashPlan simply didn't work at all (app wouldn't start).

Arq can do the job, but it doesn't just copy the file, instead it frames the disk image in its own backup structure. I guess I could compromise and use this, but then the restore process will have the additional step of remembering to use Arq. Would be better if I just had a disk image file in Dropbox directly.

Closest I came was to set up a cron job that would use [dropbox_uploader.sh](https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader) which could otherwise do the job, but it doesn't support incremental uploading, which makes it impractical (the backup is about 300GB).

I happen to prefer Dropbox, but only because I already have a lot of space there, but I can consider any other option as well.

Comment: Why not also copy direct to a sparse bundle on dropbox as well as your NAS?

Comment: @Mark How would you copy to Dropbox?

Comment: Copy (or rsync) to the local shared areal

Comment: @Mark There wouldn't be enough space to have a clone of the disk on the same disk itself.